Add legend title with ggplot, 'fill=' not working
I'm trying to add a legend title using ggplot, but the usual labs(fill = "XXX") function isn't working. Does anyone have any idea why?
Here's the code thus far:
img_summary %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = fantasy_group, y = mean_think, fill = fantasy_type)) +
  geom_col(colour = "black", width = .7, position = position_dodge(.7)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean_think - 1*se_think,
                    ymax = mean_think + 1*se_think), 
                    position = position_dodge(.7), width = .25) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Dominant", "Intimacy", "Promiscuous", "Submissive")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,100, by = 10), limits = c(0,100), expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#3B3B3B', '#656465', '#A0A0A0', '#D3D3D3'),
                    labels = c("Being dominant", "Being loved", "Impersonal sex", "Being submissive")) +
  labs(x = "Fantasy Group", y = "Mean Time Thinking (0-100)", title = "Figure 1: Mean percentage of time thinking of each fantasy type by fantasy group", fill = "Fantasy Type") +
  theme_apa()


I've tried fill = "Fantasy Type" and colour = "Fantasy Type" but no legend title appears.
I've looked through a whole bunch of others question pages and can't seem to find the right solution.

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What version of ggplot are you using? Does it work without the theme?

theme_apa from the jtools package has a parameter whose default is legend.use.title = FALSE. In the code comments (https://rdrr.io/cran/jtools/src/R/theme_apa.R) it notes:

There are some things to keep in mind about APA style figures:

...In some cases, users can forgo a legend in favor of describing the figure in a caption (also written in the word processor/typesetter).
Legends are typically embedded on the coordinate plane of the figure rather than next to it, as is default in \code{ggplot2}...


You presumably need to set that parameter to TRUE to make the legend title display normally.  Otherwise the theme is running legend.title = ggplot2::element_blank() to make any text that would have appeared as the legend title be blank.
You could also overwrite this by adding after theme_apa() the line + theme(legend.title = ggplot2::element_text(size = rel(0.8))) to match the code in https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/main/R/theme-defaults.R
